# Problema ao consumir API Rest

Tags: java, web-service, rest, restful

estou tentando consumir uma api, porem nao esta devolvendo uma lista interna, só retorna totalSize e done.

Codigo:

```
    public List<PessoaResponseDTO> get(String url) throws Exception {
    List<PessoaResponseDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try {
    
    url = "api.com/query/?q=select+id+,+name+,+CPF__C+from+individual";
    
    
    String accessToken = new TokenUtil().recuperaToken();
    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
    
    ResponseEntity<PessoaResponseDTO> entity = new RestTemplate().exchange(
    url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(headers),
    PessoaResponseDTO.class);
    
    list = Arrays.asList(entity.getBody());
    
    
    
    
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException clientError) {
    loggerError.error(clientError.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    loggerError.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
    }
```

```
classe PessoaResponseDTO
```

```
    @SerializedName("totalSize")
    private String totalSize;
    
    @SerializedName("done")
    private Boolean done;
    
    @SerializedName("records")
    private List<ListaPessoasDTO> records = null;
    
    
    public PessoaResponseDTO() {}
```

Alguem poderia ajudar, ja passaram por isso?

Comment: Olá Alan, tudo bem? Você pode formatar seu código em fonte monoespaçada no StackOverflow envolvendo ele com 3 acentos graves (```) antes e depois do código. Isso vai facilitar pra que as pessoas leiam seu código e te ajudem. Se não ficou claro, dá uma olhada [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). `System.out.println("O seu código vai ficar tipo assim!");`

Comment: valeu pela dica

Comment: Você já consumiu essa api por algum programa (como o Postman) para confirmar se esse é o retorno dela mesmo?

Comment: Bruno, consegui resolver colocando anotacao @JsonProperty